# Getting large Facebook photos efficiently

Tags: android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK version 2.5 on Android and would like to access the photos of an user. Therefor I am using the user_photos permission and the photos edge. Basically retrieving images is not a problem. This could be done with the Graph API call

```
me/photos?fields=images.
```

This returns for example

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 1200,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/t31.0-8/12748066_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_o.jpg",
          "width": 1600
        },
        {
          "height": 960,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/t31.0-8/p960x960/12748066_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_o.jpg",
          "width": 1280
        },
        {
          "height": 720,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t1.0-9/12729304_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_n.jpg?oh=0405c0dddc0ce13f7d5ce646a7866041&oe=5787E738",
          "width": 960
        },
        {
          "height": 600,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/t31.0-0/p600x600/12748066_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_o.jpg",
          "width": 800
        },
        {
          "height": 480,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t1.0-0/p480x480/12729304_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_n.jpg?oh=8e5c785d88737d275f1958bffd8e28d5&oe=5787B2CD",
          "width": 640
        },
        {
          "height": 320,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t1.0-0/p320x320/12729304_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_n.jpg?oh=bd747db36d52794abd65b3865149d827&oe=57BC3F8F",
          "width": 426
        },
        {
          "height": 540,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/t31.0-0/p180x540/12748066_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_o.jpg",
          "width": 720
        },
        {
          "height": 130,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t1.0-0/p130x130/12729304_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_n.jpg?oh=67dfa35a5be1c78a8b2c2823f06e917e&oe=577D1D9F",
          "width": 173
        },
        {
          "height": 225,
          "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t1.0-0/p75x225/12729304_10153276753262102_6141720567752387908_n.jpg?oh=474198feca51172b40b62893fdcca398&oe=57BD1929",
          "width": 300
        }
      ]
     // other stuff
    }
  ]
   // other stuff
}.
```

This might be alright but it is way too much information (especially when receiving 100 photos). I just need one size of all images so I try to limit the information included in the images array. Unfortunately all I achieved is that the height and width information is excluded with this call:

```
me/photos?fields=images.fields(source).
```

Anyway there are still all sizes of one image. In my opinion it is still too much information received from Facebook which I do not use. So what I basically want is a Graph API call to get a lot of images and minimize the unused information received. I just need one size per image, something like

```
me/photos?fields=images.limit(1)
```

but unfortunately this call will not limit the images array. Does anyone know how to solve ?